# Can I receive a message after a user has entered their credentials to make an In App Purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to receive a message so that I can show a "Processing..." overlay while the app is communicating with the App Store to complete the In App Purchase. Is there a callback that will fire only once the user has entered their credentials so that I'm not showing the "Processing..." behind the UIAlertView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a callback for exactly this, I just missed it. The `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`'s method `paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions` will get called whenever the transaction state changes, including when it changes to `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing`, so you can do something like this:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
    if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing) {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```